# Safely setup Ubuntu vm with Terraform and Cloud-init

Tags: docker, ubuntu, terraform, cloud-init

For personal use (and fun) I'm trying to setup a VM on which I want to host my website (Nginx, Django and Postgres running in docker containers). I'm trying to learn how to setup the server using Terraform and Cloud init in a safe manner.

My current cloud-init code:

```
#cloud-config
groups:
  - docker
users:
  - default
  # the docker service account
  - name: test
    shell: /bin/bash
    home: /home/test
    groups: docker
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_import_id: None
    lock_passwd: true
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa my_public_ssh_key
package_update: true
package_upgrade: true
packages:
  - git
  - sudo
  - apt-transport-https
  - ca-certificates
  - curl
  - gnupg-agent
  - software-properties-common
runcmd:
  # install docker following the guide: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
  - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  - sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
  - sudo apt-get -y update
  - sudo apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
  - sudo systemctl enable docker
  # install docker-compose following the guide: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/
  - sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
power_state:
  mode: reboot
  message: Restarting after installing docker & docker-compose
```

The VM is Ubuntu 20.04
Technically I want the "test" user to be able to pull the latest code from my git repo and (re-)deploy the website (in /home/test/website) using docker-compose. Is it possible that the user does not have sudo permissions (I don't want to have it have elevated permissions). And secondly: how do I create a root account with a separate SSH key (and would this be a safe setup)?

The Terraform code that produces the VM.

```
resource "scaleway_instance_server" "app_server" {
  type     = var.instance_type
  image    = "ubuntu-focal"
  name     = var.instance_name
  enable_ipv6 = true

  tags = [ "FocalFossa", "MyUbuntuInstance" ]

  root_volume {
    size_in_gb = 20
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  ip_id = scaleway_instance_ip.public_ip.id

  security_group_id = scaleway_instance_security_group.www.id

  # cloud init: setup
  cloud_init = file("${path.module}/cloud-init.yml")
}
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible TF code which creates the instance and uses your current cloud-init?

Comment: I've added the Terraform code, it is not that special though..

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that the user does not have sudo permissions (I don't want to have it have elevated permissions).

Anything run by cloud-init is run as root, including the bootcmd/runcmd commands. To run things as a different user, you can use `sudo` in your runcmd.

```
sudo -u test whoami >> /var/tmp/run_cmd
```

would write `test` to `/var/tmp/run_cmd`.

> And secondly: how do I create a root account with a separate SSH key (and would this be a safe setup)?

Your `users` section would something look like this.

```yaml
users:
  - default
  # the docker service account
  - name: test
    shell: /bin/bash
    home: /home/test
    groups: docker
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    lock_passwd: true
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa my-public-key
  - name: root
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa root-public-key
disable_root: false
```

Is it safe? I think that's debatable, but there's a reason root login is disabled by default. It should be possible to ssh into the default user and then `sudo su` for your root access needs.

Also, just FYI, the `ssh_import_id: None` in your config was raising an exception in the cloud-init log because it was trying to import an ssh id for user `None`.

Comment: I actually meant that I want the user to be able to run docker after the VM has been initialized by cloud-init. The question is: can the user run docker without elevated permissions (so without super user rights). And the second question: do I need a root user with full permissions at all (after the VM has been setup by cloud-init)?